# No method error when using pagy gem -Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagy

I am trying to use pagy gem but I am getting no method error.

In my controller, I previously have

```
def index
    @hires = [*current_user.student_hires.order('created_at desc')]


    current_user.groups.includes(:group_hires).each do |group|
      @hires.push(*group.group_hires.order('created_at desc'))
    end

    @hires = @hires.uniq(&:id)

end
```

but since I want to use Pagy, I changed it to

```
def index
    @pagy, @hires = pagy([*current_user.student_hires.order('created_at desc')])


    current_user.groups.includes(:group_hires).each do |group|
      @hires.push(*group.group_hires.order('created_at desc'))
    end

    @hires = @hires.uniq(&:id)
end
```

and in my view, I have

```
<%== render partial: 'pagy/nav', locals: {pagy: @pagy} %>
```

But I am getting

```
undefined method `offset' for [#<Hire id: 12, grade: "Grade 1"
```

I am using pagy in another simpler controller and it works well but I can't get it to work on this controller index.

Comment: What is the purpose of `[*current_user.student_hires.order('created_at desc')]`? Why not simply use `current_user.student_hires.order('created_at desc')`?

Comment: You might want to check out the [docs](https://ddnexus.github.io/pagy). The `pagy` method expects a scope, not an array. Remove that `[*` ... `]` wrapper.

Comment: I need it to be an array because of the other part of the index function, it throws error if it's not an array

Comment: If you need both, you could use `scope = current_user.student_hires.order('created_at desc')`. With that, you can call `pagy(scope)` and assign `@hires = scope.to_a` (which is the same as `@hires = [*scope]` but less geeky)

Comment: @stefan I'm a little confused with the pagy(scope), can you post the full function as an answer so I would understand better

Comment: so just `pagy(current_user.student_hires.order('created_at desc'))`

Comment: @MozartLen I hesitate to write an answer because I'm not sure if this will actually fix your problem. It's more a guess of what _could_ work :-)

Comment: I was able to fix it using `pagy_array`

So I did 

    @pagy, @hires = pagy_array([*current_user.student_hires.order('created_at desc')])

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it using `pagy_array`

So I did

```
@pagy, @hires = pagy_array([*current_user.student_hires.order('created_at desc')])
```

and also added `require 'pagy/extras/array'` to the config/initializers

More instruction about it is here https://ddnexus.github.io/pagy/extras/array#gsc.tab=0